# How to highlight border of input field in red color if i does not enter the data in Vuejs?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

```css
.input-section {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 359px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0 45px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #b1b8c9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" v-model="fullname" v-model.trim="$v.fullname.$model" :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.fullname) }" class="input-section" v-on:keypress="isLetter($event)" placeholder="Enter your name" />


<input class="input-section label-set" type="text" id="mobile" v-model="mobile" v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model" :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.mobile) }" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" v-on:keypress="isMobile($event)" />
```

How would I highlight the border of the input field in red? Suppose I have two fields. Without entering one field if user try to enter in the second field, then the border color of the first field should change to red, else to normal.

I have an idea to do this using bootstrap Form-control but, I want to use it in css.

Answer (score 1):

CSS can style an input element based on it's value attribute, for example:

```css
input#mobile:not([value]) {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

but you are not necessarily able to pick up the HTML Element / Node's value as it is being changed in real-time. For that you're probably going to need some kind of scripted solution.

You could use the [`oninput` event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) to capture user input and update the value attribute accordingly, but if you're using a framework - you may want to set the value attribute using that instead.

```html
<input type="text" id="mobile" oninput="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use in this way:

```
/* If input is not empty */
input:not(:placeholder-on) {
  /* You need to add a placeholder to your fields. For example: <input "placeholder=" "/> */
  border-color: green;
}

/* If input is empty */
input:placeholder-on {
  border-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I am already having placeholder for my input field, So  in the css input based on my input class given. if have given as input:not(:placeholder-on){..} and input:placeholder-on {...} But i am not getting any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged ***JavaScript*** in your question, here is how you can do it in JS.

Run over the selectors nodeList using querySelectorAll then add a blur eventListener on the eventTarget and check to see if the current looped elements value is set to nothing or only has white space, `e.target.value.trim().length == 0`, if it is, add a class that changes the style of the input tag else remove that class if it is not empty.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input-section')

inputs.forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('blur', (e) => {
    if(e.target.value.trim().length == 0){
      e.target.classList.add('warning')
    }else{
      e.target.classList.remove('warning')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.input-section {
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 359px;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
  padding: 0 45px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #b1b8c9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.warning {
  border: solid 2px #F00;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" v-model="fullname" v-model.trim="$v.fullname.$model" :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.fullname) }" class="input-section" v-on:keypress="isLetter($event)" placeholder="Enter your name" />


<input class="input-section label-set" type="text" id="mobile" v-model="mobile" v-model.trim="$v.mobile.$model" :class="{ 'is-invalid': validationStatus($v.mobile) }" placeholder="Enter your mobile number" v-on:keypress="isMobile($event)" />
```